# How to pass variables to lua function in cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, lua, cocos2d-x

I am trying to call lua functions in cocos2d-x. However when I try to pass some variables to lua functions. My program stopped at `lua_call()`.

My function:

```
const char* getData::callLuaFunction(const char* luaFileName,const char* functionName){
    lua_State*  ls = CCLuaEngine::defaultEngine()->getLuaStack()->getLuaState();

    std::string filefullpath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils()->fullPathForFilename(luaFileName);
    const char* pfilefullpath = filefullpath.c_str();
    int isOpen = luaL_dofile(ls, pfilefullpath);
    if(isOpen!=0){
        CCLOG("Open Lua Error: %i", isOpen);
        return NULL;
    }

    lua_getglobal(ls, functionName);

    lua_pushstring(ls, "einverne");
    lua_pushnumber(ls, 2);
    lua_pushboolean(ls, true);

    lua_call(ls, 3, 1);
    const char* iResult = lua_tostring(ls, -1);
    return iResult;
}
```

Function in lua file:

```
function luaLogString(_logStr,_logNum,_logBool)
    print("Lua string from C：",_logStr,_logNum,_logBool)
    return "call lua function OK"
end
```

Edit:
I have found `lua_call` is not protected. `lua_pcall` function is safer. And after I changed to `lua_pcall`. Errors show that `attempt to call global '聽聽聽聽print' (a nil value)`

Comment: Is there an error being emitted?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I cannot find a error, it just stopped.

Comment: Something wrong with `lua_atpanic`

Answer (score 3):

Actually I found the problem.

I delete four space before `print` function in lua file and everything is OK.

And I suggest newbie to use `lua_pcall` rather than `lua_call`. Because if there is an error when calling `lua_call` , this function will call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` and shutdown host program without giving an error message.

The difference between `lua_pcall` and `lua_call`

- [English version](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pcall)
- [Chinese version](http://www.codingnow.com/2000/download/lua_manual.html#lua_pcall)